# Threatening email sent to me from my email address (from email address same as to address)

Tags: email, spam, hacking

I received an email earlier today on my work email address

The email came from the same address - mine but I didn't send it

It was an email claiming that he was a professional hacker and had hacked my operating system and planted harmful spy warehouse

The email also asked for 1300 USD worth of bitcoin.

My question is

How does someone send an email from my email address if they have no access?

Is there anything I can do to check if this is a legitimate threat or purely a spoof?

I have checked my sent items and this email is not showing.

Of this is a spoof, is there anything I can do to the DKIM/SPF to ensure that this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Spoofing the 'from' field of an email is trivial.  But this isn't a webmaster question.

Comment: I've flagged this to be moved to superuser.com

Comment: Questions here are required to be about [operating and managing your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). These are [very common](https://consumer.ftc.gov/consumer-alerts/2020/04/scam-emails-demand-bitcoin-threaten-blackmail), you can just mark it as spam and delete it. As commented above, email spoofing is very easy to do. You can view the headers to see what IP address it was received from, do an [IP address lookup](https://search.arin.net/rdap/) and then send a complaint to the abuse or admin of that IP's network.

Comment: If you have access to your mail server, you can block that IP address or range. You can also report the IP address to [blacklist sites](https://www.abuseipdb.com/) - many mailers use their databases to classify incoming email as spam. Likely they'll be using different IP's via proxies or open/hacked SMTPs though, so that might not be worth the effort. Just setting up an email filter to mark the same subject or content as junk is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

The likely way this was done was by someone simply setting your address as the sender email address and sending it.

You can see where the email was sent from by looking in the full headers of the message.  This will give you an indication of the senders IP and server they sent it through.

You can indeed use SPF to frustrate this kind of activity.  Its as easy as adding a record into your DNS which says "people at this domain only ever send email from these IP's/systems".  Exactly how you do this depends on how your email is set up and who your provider is.    You would want to ask your email provider for this information.  (But also bear in mind if you send out mail blasts or have a web form which sends email as you you will need to include these details as well).

I comment that SPF works at a per domain record - so if the sender sent it from within your network it won't help you - and it won't provide much protection if your email address is (something)@gmail.com or equivalent.